# Docker image exists, but "docker run" doesn't find it

Tags: docker

Here is the link of docker hub from where I am pulling the image "https://hub.docker.com/r/zcgzcgzcg/squadv2/tags"

My main motive is to run the environment on my machine locally.

[image: ouput]

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify which version of `zcgzcgzcg/squadv2` you want, Docker will, per default use the tag `latest`.

But you don't have any image `zcgzcgzcg/squadv2:latest`.
You have one tagged `4.0`, though, so:

```
docker run zcgzcgzcg/squadv2:4.0
```

Is what you are looking for.

This is implicitly described in the documentation where they point at the fact that:

> ```
> $ docker run --name test -it debian
> ```
>
> This example runs a container named `test` using the `debian:latest` image.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#assign-name-and-allocate-pseudo-tty---name--it*</sup>

But it is also explicitly descriped in the `docker pull` page:

> If no tag is provided, Docker Engine uses the `:latest` tag as a default.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not specifying the `tag` in your `docker run` command. You have pulled `4.0`, as you can see in the `docker images` output - but when you don't specify the tag, it will default to `latest` - which you don't have. So, try this:

`docker run zcgzcgzcg/squadv2:4.0`